# Evaluate: $ \int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x - \cos x} dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Consider

$$ \int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x - \cos x} dx $$

Well I tried taking integrand as $ \frac{\sin x - \cos x + \cos x}{\sin x - \cos x} $ so that it becomes,

$$ 1 + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x - \cos x} $$

But does not helps.
I want different techniques usable here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set

$$ I = \int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x - \cos x} dx = \int 1 + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x - \cos x} dx$$

Therefore:

$$ 2I = \int 1 + \frac{\sin x +\cos x}{\sin x - \cos x} dx $$

$$ 2I = x + \log(\sin x - \cos x) + C$$

$$ I = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \log(\sin x - \cos x) + C$$

Comment: Amazed to see your answer

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way, according to *Bioche's rules*, is to use the substitution
$$t=\tan x, \quad \mathrm dx=\frac{ \mathrm dt}{1+t^2},$$
which transforms the integral into the inthe integral of the rational function
$$\int\frac{t\,\mathrm dt}{(t-1)(1+t^2)}$$
There remains to decompose this fraction in partial fractions.

Comment: Can you explain *Bioche's rule* to me?

Comment: Or perhaps add a link???

Comment: It's rather simple: for  a rational function of trigonometric functions $F$, consider the differential form $\omega(x)=F(\sin x, \cos x)\,\mathrm d x$. If $\omega(-x)=\omega(x)$, set $t=\cos x$. If  $\omega(\pi-x)=\omega(x)$, set $t=\sin x$ .If  $\omega(\pi+x)=\omega(x)$, set $t=\tan x$ (taking into account that $\mathrm d(-x)=-\mathrm d x$, &c).

Comment: I forgot: if two cases happen to be true, set $t=\sin 2x$ or $\cos 2x$ or $\tan 2x$ (depending on which cases are tue). If none is true, you always can set $t=\tan \frac x2$.

Comment: I know a link, but it's in French: [Règles de Bioche](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Règles_de_Bioche)

Answer (score 1):

The substitution that generally works when you are integrating a function containing sines and cosines is
$$ u = \tan \frac{x}{2}.$$
Then you can show that
$$ dx = \frac{2\,du}{1+x^2}, \quad \sin x= \frac{2x}{1+x^2}, \quad \text{and} \quad \cos x = \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}, $$
which should transform your integrand into a rational function.

Comment: It's actually wiser in this case to use $u=\tan x$ because the integrand's period is only half that of the individual sine/cosine functions.

Comment: @J.G. Very wise indeed, thanks for suggesting that! =)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$I_{1} = \int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x - \cos x}dx, \quad I_{2} = \int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x - \cos x}dx$$ 
Then $$I_{1}-I_{2} = \int 1\, dx =  x + c_{1}$$
$$I_{1}+I_{2} = \int \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x - \cos x} dx = \ln(\sin x - \cos x) + c_{2} $$

Then solve simultaneously

$$I_{1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x+ \ln(\sin x - \cos x) \right) + c$$

Answer (score 0):

Take$$I=\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {\sin x}{\sin x-\cos x}$$$$J=\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {\cos x}{\sin x-\cos x}$$Subtracting gives$$I-J=\int\mathrm dx\,=x$$Adding gives$$I+J=\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x-\cos x}=\log(\sin x-\cos x)$$Take the average of the two to see that$$\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {\sin x}{\sin x-\cos x}\color{blue}{=\frac 12x+\frac 12\log(\sin x-\cos x)+C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In general for

$\displaystyle\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{a\sin x+b\cos x}{c\sin x+d\cos x}\right)}{dx}$

write numerator$(a\sin x+b\cos x)$ as  $A(c\sin x+d\cos x)+B\cdot\dfrac{d(c\sin x+d\cos x)}{dx}$

Compare the coefficients of $\sin x,\cos x$ to find $A,B$